# Control over the Share option when a +1 button is clicked in Android

Tags: android, google-play, google-plus, google-play-services, google-plus-one

If you click a the +1 button on an app on the Play Store you get the option to share what you've +1'd with a lovely pre-filled link to the game, as follows.

[image]

I've added a +1 button to the game itself. The button displays Google's +1 dialog. This includes a "Share" button which I was hoping would do the same thing. The share button however just starts a completely blank share intent. Example images at the bottom.

Is there a way for me to manually initialise the share intent so I can pre-populate it with text? Can I do something with the Intent passed to me in onActivityResult? Or can I hide the share button? Either option is preferable to the default behaviour.

The code to create the button.

```
private void createPlusButton() {

    AndroidLauncher.application.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            plusOneButton = new PlusOneButton(AndroidLauncher.application);

            plusOneButton.setAnnotation(PlusOneButton.ANNOTATION_NONE);
            plusOneButton.setSize(PlusOneButton.SIZE_TALL);
            plusOneButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams plusButtonParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            plusButtonParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
            plusButtonParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
            plusButtonParams.bottomMargin = 15;
            AndroidLauncher.application.layout.addView(plusOneButton, plusButtonParams);

            initialisePlusOneButton();
        }
    });
}

public void initialisePlusOneButton() {
    if (plusOneButton != null)
        plusOneButton.initialize("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wrc.wordstorm.android", PLUS_ONE_REQUEST);
}
```

[image] [image]

Comment: You want to add pre-filled text to Share button ?